# What's the fastest way to filter a table of integers in Python?

Tags: python, sql, performance, list, numpy

I have a dataset that consists of 7 columns and ~900k rows. All columns are non-unique, and all values are integers.

Two important conditions for the filtering:

- I strictly want to see which values there are in one column when I apply conditions on the rest.
- For the output I am only interested in distinct values.

As an example here is the SQL query used for benchmarking performance:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
col_2
FROM dataset
WHERE
c_1 in (1,9,5,6,8,18,14,7,15) AND
c_3 in (1) AND
c_4 in (61) AND
c_5 in (3) AND
c_6 in (0) AND
c_7 in (0)
```

The first approach I tried was SQL with indices using SQLite, which didn't do too bad, but as the filters return a lot of row the performance dropped.

I then tried plain vanilla list comprehensions in Python. The performance was a bit worse than in the SQL case.

Are there any better ways of doing this? I was thinking in the direction of numpy, perhaps using a more efficient data structure than lists and SQL tables?

I am very much interested in speed and performance here, and less so of efficiency.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Sounds indeed like a DB is not the best way to store this. Have you thought of using [Cython](http://cython.org/)? Could be rather storage efficient (you can use machine words) and quite fast (for the same reason) when you add static type annotations.

Comment: When you tried SQLite was your DB in memory or on disk? If it was on a file try using `:memory:`, in-memory databases with sqlite can often be much faster than python for tasks like this. Were ALL your columns indexed?

Comment: I agree a DB solution is not really the best option here, I used it more as a benchmarking tool. I am putting together a c-extension as an experiment. I wonder however if there is an efficient way of doing this in Numpy, which is unchartered territory for me.

Comment: @Giuseppe, good catch. I will try that out. Although I think it still won't be fast enough.

Comment: What's the distribution of integers like in these columns?

Comment: One column has ~400 values, while the rest have ~20 each. Pretty much evenly distributed.

Comment: So what you're after is a quick method of searching a loaded dataset? As opposed to a quick way of loading and searching a dataset?

Comment: Exactly. The dataset is small enough to be kept in memory so that's no problem. So far list comprehensions are the fastest. I am slightly curious to see what the performance of a c-extension would be though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on what you've said about 20 or so distinct values per column except one with 400. If memory and load time isn't a worry, then I'd suggest creating sets per value per column.

Here's something to generate a sample dataset.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from random import sample, choice
from cPickle import dump

# Generate sample dataset
value_ceiling = 1000
dataset_size = 900000
dataset_filename = 'dataset.pkl'

# number of distinct values per column
col_distrib = [400,20,20,20,20,20,20]

col_values = [ sample(xrange(value_ceiling),x) for x in col_distrib ]

dataset = []
for _ in xrange(dataset_size):
  dataset.append(tuple([ choice(x) for x in col_values ]))

dump(dataset,open(dataset_filename,'wb'))
```

Here's something to load the dataset and create lookup sets per value per column, a search method and creation of sample searches.

```
#/usr/bin/python

from random import sample, choice
from cPickle import load

dataset_filename = 'dataset.pkl'

class DataSearch(object):
  def __init__(self,filename):
    self.data = load(open(filename,'rb'))
    self.col_sets = [ dict() for x in self.data[0] ]
    self.process_data()
  def process_data(self):
    for row in self.data:
      for i,v in enumerate(row):
        self.col_sets[i].setdefault(v,set()).add(row)
  def search(self,*args):
    # args are integers, sequences of integers, or None in related column positions.
    results = []
    for i,v in enumerate(args):
      if v is None:
        continue
      elif isinstance(v,int):
        results.append(self.col_sets[i].get(v,set()))
      else: # sequence
        r = [ self.col_sets[i].get(x,set()) for x in v ]
        r = reduce(set.union,r[1:],r[0])
        results.append(r)
    #
    results.sort(key=len)
    results = reduce(set.intersection,results[1:],results[0])
    return results
  def sample_search(self,*args):
    search = []
    for i,v in enumerate(args):
      if v is None:
        search.append(None)
      else:
        search.append(sample(self.col_sets[i].keys(),v))
    return search

d = DataSearch(dataset_filename)
```

And using it:

```
>>> d.search(*d.sample_search(1,1,1,5))
set([(117, 557, 273, 437, 639, 981, 587), (117, 557, 273, 170, 53, 640, 467), (117, 557, 273, 584, 459, 127, 649)])
>>> d.search(*d.sample_search(1,1,1,1))
set([])
>>> d.search(*d.sample_search(10,None,1,1,1,1))
set([(801, 334, 414, 283, 107, 990, 221)])
>>> d.search(*d.sample_search(10,None,1,1,1,1))
set([])
>>> d.search(*d.sample_search(10,None,1,1,1,1))
set([(193, 307, 547, 549, 901, 940, 343)])
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.Timer('d.search(*d.sample_search(10,None,1,1,1,1))','from __main__ import d').timeit(100)
1.787431001663208
```

1.8 seconds to do 100 searches fast enough?

Comment: I completely forgot sets, very quick indeed. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with:

```
513 $ cat filtarray.py
#!/usr/bin/python2
#
import numpy
import itertools

a = numpy.fromiter(xrange(7*900000), int)
a.shape = (900000,7)
# stuff a known match
a[33][0] = 18
a[33][2] = 1
a[33][3] = 61
# filter it, and make list, but that is not strictly necessary.
res = list(itertools.ifilter(lambda r: r[0] in (1,9,5,6,8,18,14,7,15) and r[2] == 1 and r[3] == 61, a))
print res
```

Run it on Intel E8400:

```
512 $ time python filtarray.py 
[array([ 18, 232,   1,  61, 235, 236, 237])]
python filtarray.py  5.36s user 0.05s system 99% cpu 5.418 total
```

Is that faster?

Comment: yea I tried that one too. List comprehensions are faster though, and slightly more readable IMHO. Thanks regardless

Answer (score 0):

Here's a numpy version, it takes about 1 second.

```
x = numpy.random.randint(0, 100, (7, 900000))

def filter(data, filters):
    indices = []
    for i, filter in enumerate(filters):
        indices.append(numpy.any([data[i] == x for x in filter], 0))

    indices = numpy.all(indices, 0)
    return data[indices]

# Usage:
filter(x, [(1,9,5,6,8,18,14,7,15), (1,), (61,), (3,), (0,), (0,)])

%timeit filter(x, [(1,9,5,6,8,18,14,7,15), (1,), (61,), (3,), (0,), (0,)])
1 loops, best of 3: 903 ms per loop
```

Comment: I played around with the filter function too. Like the itertools answer above, list comprehensions are easier to read though.

Comment: Numpy's vectorized approach is hard to beat from a performance standpoint, but it does require the programmer (and the reader) to think in a vectorial way.  An intermediate solution would be to use something like numpexr or weave.inline.